# Do I have to reinstall Windows security software after installing Ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation

I am completly new to ubuntu and a dual boot system. I have a Toshiba laptop with an i7 processor, 64 bit system with Windows 8 installed. I would like to install ubuntu as a dual boot and want to know if there is anything special I should do or watch for haveing  Windows8 installed. Once ubuntu is installed will I have to reinstall security software that I installed in Windows to protect my pc in ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu will have it's own partition, nothing will change withing Windows, just that you will notice some hard disk space missing that you assinged to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

To start off, always install Windows 8 first. Windows 8 will write over the MBR and that will make Ubuntu unbootable if you have it installed. Once Windows 8 is installed, You can dual boot Ubuntu. Ubuntu will make changes to the MBR so that GRUB can boot either Ubuntu or chain boot Windows 8.

Ubuntu is far less prone to viruses than Windows. People will say,

> Ubuntu can be infected by a virus just as easily as Windows can

This is kind of true. Ubuntu does have the occasional security hole. The difference is that there are not nearly as many viruses out there for Ubuntu. Ubuntu doesn't need anti-virus and it won't for a very long time (knock on wood). Don't get anti-virus software for Ubuntu, it's a waste.

If you are seriously concerned with your security on Ubuntu check out:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BasicSecurity

One thing I would really encourage is for you to encrypt your Ubuntu installation. This way if you get a virus in Windows, then the virus won't be able to infect your Ubuntu installation.